# Nodejs code to convert hex string to byte array?

Tags: java, node.js

Can anyone please tell me equivalent `Nodejs` code to convert hex string to byte array which is in `Java`

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    byte[] b = new byte[s.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        int index = i * 2;
        int v = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
        b[i] = (byte) v;

    }
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`Buffer.from(str, [encoding])`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) to perform the conversion.

```
Buffer.from(str, 'hex');
```